# ngResource new instance error when call $query

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Let's say I have a $resource like:

```
var Collections = $resource("http://somedomain/collections/:action", {
  action: "@action"
});
```

If I create a new instance

```
var myCollections = new Collections()
```

When I do

```
myCollections.$query();
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: value.push is not a function
```

Now, the response is an array as expected and everything seems to be in order.
If I do

```
var myCollections = Collections.query();
```

it works

Any ideas why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Any news on a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using $resource in that way, I do believe there is no such thing is a $query(), only query() with no dollar sign in front of it. There is a $save() which I think can get pretty confusing.

I wish the documentation was a bit better on this subject, but one way to see all your possible calls on that object is checking under the prototype for when you console.log myCollections. That, and searching examples on the web.

Comment: I checked and the methods are all preceded with `$`. So there *is* a `$query()` method. The funny thing is that calling `$save` or `$remove` works, but calling `$query` raises an error.